# npm start doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, windows-10

I have just moved from `linux ubuntu` to `windows` and here first errors. When i try to restart the app i receive this errors.And every time i have to restart the whole computer in order to see the changes.After restarting the whole computer `npm start` works fine.
i tried to `update` the `npm` but no result.
Could anyone help?

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! exproject@1.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the exproject@1.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the exproject package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs exproject
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls exproject
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\Users\sashi\Desktop\nprojects\basicexpress\exproject\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score -1):

chage

```
  "scripts": {
     "start": "./bin/www"
  },
```

To

```
  "scripts": {
     "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
```